# Do there exist 5-reguler planar, 3-connected (4 or 5 connected?) hamiltonian graphs which are not pancyclic?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

A graph $G$ with $n$ vertices is called *pancyclic* if it contains cycles of length $m$, for every value of $m$ such that $3 \le m \le n$.
The question as stated originates from the article [1] by Malkevitch et al., who posed three problems. I am particularly interested in the first problem, but I am not sure if it has already been solved by someone, as it has been over 50 years.

**Problem 1 [1]**  Do there exist 5-valent planar, 3-connected (4 or 5 connected?) hamiltonian graphs which are not pancyclic?

Perhaps this question is just a routine exercise? My intuition tells me it exists.

[1]  J. Malkevitch, On lengths of cycles in planar graphs. Recent Trends in Graph Theory. Springer-Verlag, Berlin (1971) 191-195.

Comment: At the very least, Mathematica's `GraphData` has no such graphs. (The 5-regular planar graphs that it knows are all fairly standard graphs, so I imagine Malkevitch might have checked them manually in 1971.)

Comment: @kabenyuk Yes. You are right.

Comment: If you try to construct such a graph, note that Susan A. van Aardt, Marietjie Fricka, Ortrud R. Oellermannb, Johan de Wet have proved in 2016 the following theorem. *If $G$ is a locally connected graph with $\Delta(G) \le 5$, then $G$ is weakly pancyclic.* It means that your graph should have at least one vertex which belongs to at least two faces of size at least $4$.